# ASP.NET Bundle including resource with custom html attribute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, bundle

If I want to include a JS script like:

```
<script src="../ClientTestFramework/Blanket/blanket.js" data-cover-adapter="../ClientTestFramework/Blanket/jasmine-blanket.js">
```

**NB: with the extra html attribute**

How can I do this with a ASP.NET Bundle?

Answer (score 1):

From the [bundling tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification):

> You can use the Url method to generate the URL to the asset without
>   the markup needed to reference the asset.

Adapted to your code:

```
<script src="@Scripts.Url("~/ClientTestFramework/Blanket/blanket.js")" data-cover-adapter="../ClientTestFramework/Blanket/jasmine-blanket.js">
```